# Primes of the form $a^2+3b^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I realise there is quite a bit of material online regarding primes of the form $p = a^2 + 3b^2$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, none provide the information I am looking for.

I am trying to prove that if $p$ is a prime with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ then there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p = a^2 + 3b^2$.

I want to use Minkowski's inequality and I have a hint that I should first prove that $2p = a^2 + 3b^2$ has no solutions for such primes $p$. But I don't know how to prove this, or why this would help.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $a^2$ is 0 or 1 (mod 3), $3b^2$ is 0, and you just can't get 2 (that is to say, 2p) out of that.

Comment: Do you know why for such primes there are pairs $a,b$ with $p \nmid ab$ such that $p \mid a^2 + 3b^2$? Consider the set $K = \{ k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : (\exists a,b)(a^2 + 3b^2 = k\cdot p)\}$ and $\min K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p$ is one greater than a multiple of $6$, then $2p$ is two greater than a multiple of $3$.  The sum $a^{2}+3b^{2}$ can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get this part now. But how will this help in proving that there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p=a^2+3b^2$? (If I want to use Minkowski's Theorem)